# Laravel Reuseable Functions

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `videos` table which stores details about a `video` and another `videoStats` table which stores how many times a. video has been watched.

I am creating a `Service` with some custom methods to suit the requirement of the application. I don't know if it is ideal to create a new service for the need or if I can have these methods within the model itself. If there is any other way to do it better, I would appreciate some suggestions.

I have a method `mostWatchedVideos` which returns a list with `watch_count` and `video_id` for every video.

The second method `mostWatchedVideosBetween` is supposed to return the same thing as `mostWatchedVideos` but for a certain time period. I can repeat the same code with additional argument for the date `->whereBetween('createdAt', [$from, $till])` and it would do the trick, but what I was thinking of is, since both the methods use the same code, is there a way to reuse the method but with the date filter?

```
public static function mostWatchedVideosBetween(Carbon $from, Carbon $till)
{

}

public static function mostWatchedVideos($limit = NULL)
{
    return VideoStats::select(\DB::raw('count(*) as watch_count, videoId'))
                            ->groupBy('videoId')
                            ->orderBy('watch_count', 'DESC')
                            ->limit($limit)
                            ->get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a method that returns the common query:

```
public static function getWatchCountQuery() {
    return VideoStats::select(\DB::raw('count(*) as watch_count, videoId'))
               ->groupBy('videoId')
               ->orderBy('watch_count', 'DESC');
}
```

And use that in your other methods:

```
public static function mostWatchedVideosBetween(Carbon $from, Carbon $till) {
    return $this->getWatchCountQuery()
               ->whereBetween('createdAt', [$from, $till])
               ->get();
}

public static function mostWatchedVideos($limit = NULL) {
    return $this->getWatchCountQuery()
               ->limit($limit)
               ->get();
}
```

And in my opinion that logic belongs in your model. Not in a service.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use conditional [Conditional Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#conditional-clauses). For ie, if the value/s is `null`, it will result in `false` and what is within the condition will not be taken into account:

```
public static function mostWatchedVideos($limit = NULL, $from = null, $till = null)
{
    return VideoStats::select(\DB::raw('count(*) as watch_count, videoId'))
                            ->groupBy('videoId')
                            ->orderBy('watch_count', 'DESC')
                            ->when($limit, function ($query, $limit) {
                                 return $query->limit($limit);
                            })
                            ->when(($from && $till), function ($query, $from, $till) {
                                 return $query->whereBetween('date_column', [Carbon::parse($from), Carbon::parse($till)]);
                            })
                            ->get();
}
```